# Angular.js filter shows no results on empty input

Tags: angularjs

I want to filter results from a subreddit. The following code works as intended but shows no results when the page is first loaded. When I hit space or write anything, it brings up the results. Normally angular brings all the results when the input is empty. I want all the results to be loaded when the page is first loaded.
Here is the html:

```
<body ng-app>
Search: <input ng-model="query">
<ul ng-controller="Reddit">
    <li ng-repeat="title in reddit | filter:{data.title:query} ">
        <p>{{title.data.title}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

And the script:

```
function Reddit($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json').success(function(topic){
        $scope.reddit = topic.data.children;
    });
}
```

Also you can play with it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/liquidcat/sZCE4/

Comment: check the console, you are getting a CORS issue, check the console, it has nothing to do with filter

Comment: Your fiddle has invalid syntax in ngRepeat expression and Ajax doesn't work 'cause of same origin policy.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/sZCE4/5/ but it seems to be having an issue with the JSON, but JSON Lint says JSON is fine

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to update the jsfiddle link. I hope you read the code before looking into the link. The code above filters as intended but only does not get results on the first load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `query`.

add

```
 $scope.query = '';
```

in your controller.

**EDIT** : above statement is wrong.  Sorry.

In addition to the above, your `query` variable is out of the scope.
(so just defining `query` in the controller's scope would disconnect the object...)

Here is the cleanuped / working code example.
http://plnkr.co/edit/0aT33Q2H2SQTPG4E62Zb?p=preview

Comment: It breaks the search function.

Comment: Sorry, my answer is totally wrong.  it is the filter expression.  I think you'll have to create a filter function because it does not support nested filter key.

Comment: The above code worked. I made a mistake as you mentioned, the variable was out of scope.